# Facing trouble with the return of UIApplicationMain

Tags: xcode

I have a error help me please

`2013-02-21 18:43:54.471 BPApp[12574:c07] 
*** Assertion failure in -[MainViewController saveEntry:], /Users/Apple/Desktop/BPApp/BPApp/MainViewController.m:66
2013-02-21 18:43:54.473 BPApp[12574:c07] ***`

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not update table'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2091012 0x119ee7e 0x2090e78 0xc34f35 0x313d 0x11b2705 0xe9920 0xe98b8 0x1aa671 0x1aabcf 0x1a9d38 0x11933f 0x119552 0xf73aa 0xe8cf8 0x1fecdf9 0x1fecad0 0x2006bf5 0x2006962 0x2037bb6 0x2036f44 0x2036e1b 0x1feb7e3 0x1feb668 0xe665c 0x263d 0x2565)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception.`

```
 (IBAction)saveEntry:(id)sender
{

int systolic = [systolicText.text intValue];
int diastolic = [diastolicText.text intValue];
NSString *comments = commentsText.text;
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate date];

NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO summary('theDate', 'systolic', 'diastolic', 'comments') VALUES ('%@', '%d', '%d', '%@')", theDate, systolic, diastolic, comments];

char *err;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) !=SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSAssert(0, @"Could not update table");
}else{
    NSLog(@"table updated");
}


systolicText.text =@"";
diastolicText.text =@"";
commentsText.text =@"";

}
```

is my`mainviewcontroller.m`

Answer (score 0):

As your error saying , go to the function **saveEntry** in the **MainViewController** and put the break point at the starting line of the saveEntry function , compile the code line by line . Then you can get the error at which line you are getting .

Comment: do you have the functin called saveEntry?Is it having { symbol?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your use of `NSAssert()` which should only be used to detect and reject silly developer mistakes (that we are constantly making).

You should **not** use `NSAssert()` for failures that can occur at runtime, and any database interaction can fail.

Instead you should put that code into a method that returns `BOOL` and return `NO` if the insert fails.  You should also log the reason for the failure, which you can get from sqlite3 using the function `sqlite3_errmsg()` ([reference](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)).

After that you need to handle the error by doing anything appropriate to your application; perhaps displaying an alert view and then closing the app, or retrying with different values or, well, anything you can think of to resolve the issue with the least discomfort to the user.